# Access to shadowed variable in local class

Tags: java, shadowing

I'm new to Java and I'm confused by below example

```
public class Test {
 
   int testOne(){  //member method
       int x=5;
       class inTest  // local class in member method
       {
           void inTestOne(int x){
               System.out.print("x is "+x);
               // System.out.print("this.x is "+this.x);
           }
       }
       inTest ins=new inTest(); // create an instance of inTest local class (inner class)
       ins.inTestOne(10);
       return 0;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test obj = new Test();
       obj.testOne();
   }
}
```

Why can't I access the shadowed variable in inTestOne() method with "this" keyword in line 8?

Answer (score 6):

> Why can't I access the shadowed variable in inTestOne() method with "this" keyword in line 8?

Because `x` is *not* a member variable of the class; it is a *local* variable. The keyword `this` can be used to access a member fields of the class, not local variables.

Once a variable is shadowed, you have no access to it. This is OK, because both the variable and the local inner class are yours to change; if you want to access the shadowed variable, all you need to do is renaming it (or renaming the variable that shadows it, whatever makes more sense to you).

Note: don't forget to mark the local variable `final`, otherwise you wouldn't be able to access it even when it is not shadowed.

Answer (score 2):

`this.` is used to access **members** - a local variable is not a member, so it cannot be accessed this way when it's shadowed.

Comment: And even then, `x` is effective final but not `final` so accessing it from a local class only works in Java 8+.